# how can i show the input value from on screen key board in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image: code snippet][image]
below are my code and ouput snippet any best way to show input value when click on screen key board

Comment: use angular's `ngModel` to bind values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <input #inputTag type="hidden" value="Search">
 <button (click)="typing('A')">A</button>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('inputTag') search;

typing(character){ 
        this.search.nativeElement.value.concat(character).
}
```